# join between v$sql and v$session with specifiq condition

Tags: sql, oracle, data-dictionary

I am trying to join the both tables v$sql  and v$session
my aim of this query is to know who is the user that is using the machine and what is the sql that his using.

I am searching for something similar

```
select s.sql_text
     , i.osuser 
  from v$sql s
     , v$session i 
 where i.something= s.something 
   and i.osuer='MOUDIZ'
```

Comment: Does this query work? What problems do you have?

Comment: as I explained above I want to know the user moudiz what query is he running

Answer (score 1):

I see you have an outstanding question about the difference between the two views.

v$sql the details -- if you have multiple copies of the query:

"select * from T"

in your shared pool, v$sql will have a row per query.  This can happen if user U1 and 
user U2 both have a table T and both issue "select * from T".  Those are entirely 
different queries with different plans and so on.  v$sql will have 2 rows.

v$sqlarea is a aggregate of v$sql.  It selects out DISTINCT sql.  "select * from T" will 
appear there.

Tom has answered here https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::p11_question_id:385254862843

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.USERNAME,
       a.SQL_TEXT
from   v$session s
join   v$sqlarea a on ( a.ADDRESS = s.SQL_ADDRESS )
where  s.OSUSER = 'MOUDIZ'
```

It will only show what the user is doing right now though.

This will show all the currently open cursors:

```
select  s.username, cast(substr(q.SQL_FULLTEXT,1,4000) as varchar2(4000)) sql_text
from    v$session s
join    v$open_cursor c on ( s.SADDR = c.SADDR )
join    v$sql q on ( q.SQL_ID = c.SQL_ID )
and     s.OSUSER = 'MOUDIZ';
```

Comment: what is the difference between sql and sqlarea ? @jens

Comment: I cant tell you - many of the v$ views seem to be somewhat overlapping in content. Different perspectives I guess.

Comment: V$sqlarea is an aggregate of v$sql. More information can be seen in the underlying query of the view.